# Using Lambda with function that takes argument from different columns of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I want to learn how to use lambdas with this type of setting without using a for loop which a function takes arguments from rows of two columns of the dataframe and write the result to another column.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3], "B": [2,3,4]})

print(df)

df["C"] = ""

print(df)

def add_num(num1 ,num2):
    return num1 + num2

for i in range(len(df)):
   df["C"][i] = add_num(df["A"][i], df["B"][i])
print(df)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `apply` on the df passing arg `axis=1` this will iterate row wise, you can then sub-select the columns of interest in the `lambda` to pass to your func:

```
In [49]:    
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3], "B": [2,3,4]})
df["C"] = ""
​
def add_num(num1 ,num2):
    return num1 + num2
​
df["C"] = df.apply(lambda x: add_num(x["A"],  x["B"]), axis=1)
print(df)

   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  2  3  5
2  3  4  7
```

Note that one should avoid using `apply`, most operations can be performed using vectorised methods, I know this is just for learning but you should look for a numpy or other ufunc that is vectorised

Comment: One more question=) Does this version have a performance difference than the for loop version?

Comment: No, that's not true. Calling `lambda` that forwards to `add_num` function when called will be slower than directly calling `add_num` in the loop. However it may be that the loop is a bit more efficient with `apply`. But my guess is that the abstraction with `lambda` will be slower.

Comment: @MSeifert I was referring to the `apply` not the `lambda` portion

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3], "B": [2,3,4]})

def add_num(num1 ,num2):
    return num1 + num2

df['C'] = df.T.apply(lambda x: add_num(x['A'], x['B']))
```

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer would be: don't use `lambda` when more simple expressions work:

```
df['C'] = df['A'] + df['B']
```

Because that will use vectorized operations.

The approach with `lambda` and `apply` is already covered by @EdChum's answer so I won't show it again.